# How to trigger CSS3 scale (animation) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, css-animations

What I'd like to achieve is a pulsate effect on an action (button click for example). So what I made is this (simplified [removed browser specifics]):

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
  50% {transform: scale(1.02);}
  100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

.pulsate{
  animation-name: pulse 0.2s linear 2;
}
```

And in jQuery I did this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#some_element').addClass('pulse');
}
```

It works OK, but just the first time... Once the "pulse" class is added it doesn't trigger anymore... So what I tried to do is:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#some_element').removeClass('pulsate').addClass('pulsate');
}
```

And it still is not working... Contrary to this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('#some_element').toggleClass('pulsate');
}
```

That works the first time, not the second, but works again the third; so basically every other time.

I am baffled. Why would it work this way and not removing and adding it again? I even tried to make a reset class (once again simplified):

```
.reset_transform(){
    transform: none;
}
```

And in jQuery I'm doing something like:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e)){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#some_element').removeClass('pulsate').addClass('reset_transform').addClass('pulsate');
}
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work... Any ideas? I would like the element to pulsate every time I click the button.

Comment: If I remember well once I just added with jQuery the CSS property (NOT THE CLASS) to some element and seen the transition instantly applied to it.

Comment: is that a typo? `$('#btn').click(function(e)){` you have an extra `)`

Comment: yeah, it's a typo ;) told you I was simplifying things :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution to my problem.  As @Aspiring Aqib pointed out I needed a delay between adding and removing the Class. He used a delay() jquery but it was not working.

Here is my solution using setTimeout();

```
$('#some_element').addClass('pulsate');

setTimeout(function(){
   $('#some_element').removeClass('pulsate');
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ToggleClass()` did not worked because when you clicked it first time then it added the class and the animation played . When you clicked the second time it removed that class and this time, class is removed thats why it does not plays animation. On third time, it works like first time and this process will continue :/

```
$('#btn').click(function(e)){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#some_element').addClass('pulse').delay(200).removeClass('pulse');
}
```

well i don't think so the above code will work! :)

Comment: hm, my logic is saying that it should too... but it is not :( have to debug a little

Comment: Watching the DOM it seems that the delay is not doing it job with add/removeClass... guess I nee to make a setTimeout

Comment: OK, it works OK with setTimeout, but not set to 200. Since it pulsates 2 times the total animation time is 800ms... with a clearTimeout statement on faster clicks.... the whole thing actually looks kinda decent! thanks!

Comment: ok ok! well i don't know what to edit :) i remove my answer? bcoz i don't know how my answer helped you and i can't understand your above comment! so, if it helped you i should remove my answer!

Comment: do not remove the answer ;)

Comment: ok well give me the code you used , i edit my answer for the future issues!